# Cannot send mail including HTML tags in it using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send an email with HTML tags inside it with Laravel for which I am using Mail::raw() method.
I don't want to send a view, just want to send data as text with few HTML tags in it.

I used to below code

```
\Mail::raw("<h1>Hello</h1>", function ($message) use ($receiversEmail, $subject, $body) {
            $message->from("hello@user.com", 'A user');
            $message->to($receiversEmail);
            $message->subject($subject);
        });
```

But the HTML tags are not getting converted and hence I got a mail that reads like

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this

```
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($receiversEmail, $subject, $body) {
            $message->from("hello@user.com", 'A user');
            $message->to($receiversEmail);
            $message->subject($subject);
            $message->setBody("<h1>Hello</h1>", 'text/html');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Mail::send instead.

```
$html = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($receiversEmail, $subject, $html) {         
        $message->from("hello@user.com", 'A user');
        $message->to($receiversEmail);
        $message->subject($subject);
        $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
    });
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, altough you probably typoed and missed the starting ( but thanks, that helped